# Twitter typeahead.js asp.net not working with Bloodhound

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

I am trying to use the nuget package [Twitter.Typeahead.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Typeahead.MVC) but am having difficulty getting a simple example to work.  I have a simple input text box:

```
<div id="bloodhound">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```

In the script section I have:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
          'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
          'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
          'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
          'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
          'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
          'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
          'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
          'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        // constructs the suggestion engine
        var bhstates = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
            local: states
        });

        $('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1,
            limit: 10
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            source: bhstates
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have also included the following render statement in _Layout.cshtml

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/typeahead")
```

When the application runs, the textbox appears but I don't get any suggested values when typing in the box.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the engine after your instantiation

```
// initialize engine
bhstates.Initialize();
```